# Predictive text in Excel from a Data Validation list

Tags: excel, validation

I've been struggling with this for some time now.

Basically I am creating a form to be populated by an end user. The form has a series of questions to be populated from lists created by a data validation list. The lists extend to upwards of 10,000 possible entries. I want to add a predictive element to make it more user friendly.

An example, the lists include alpha numeric options for example for vendors: ‘5463 – Acme Supplies’ or ‘5988 – Zorn Inc”. So the vendor number and name are included.

How can I automate the selection choice in the data validation cell so that if the user knows the vendor number he can type a ‘5’ and the list of available options limits itself to those beginning with ‘5’ if the user then adds a 4, so has ‘54’ then the list limits itself to vendors with the number beginning with ‘54’?

Similarly, if the end user know the vendor name, he can enter ‘a’ and the list limits itself to vendors beginning with the letter ‘a’ if he adds a ‘c’ then the list restricts itself to vendors beginning with ‘ac’.

I am at a loss on this one and suspect excel cannot perform this task.

Comment: Hint: use range operators `OFFSET`, `COUNTA` and `MATCH`. Append `"*"` wildcards to the right end. Disable blocking input. The user will have to finish input and then return though. Unless you're willing to learn `VBA`... This will only work with aligned lists. the "a" string is unlikely to work.

Comment: Here is one approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkPoViUhkxU.  This will generally require a cell to search and a different cell with the drop down. The two will fight otherwise.